# L'Hopital with an inverse function

Tags: real-analysis

Use L'Hopital's Rule to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x{\rightarrow0}}\frac{x\cos(x)}{x+\arcsin(x)}$$
Here $\arcsin:(-1,1)\rightarrow(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$ is the inverse function of the sine function.

If we let $f(x)=x\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=x+\arcsin(x)$, we obviously know that $f$ is differentiable but how do we know that $g$ is differentiable?

We know that $\sin(x)$ is a differentiable function but we can't use the inverse function theorem and the inverse function theorem for differentiability to say that $\arcsin(x)$ is differentiable because our intervals for this function are strict.

$\sin:(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)\rightarrow(-1,1)$ does not satisfy the inverse function theorem because the intervals are strict. I don't see how you can do this question rigorously.

Comment: Of course you can. For one thing we only care about $|x|\lt0.1$.

Comment: by 0.1 do you mean the interval of x such that x is bounded by a very small number? -A<x<A where A is a number very close to zero?

Comment: It doesn't have to be *close* to $0$. The derivative of $\arcsin x$  has a little problem at $\pm 1$, but as long as you stay away from there, and stay say in $(-1/2,1/2)$ we are OK. And our limit only cares about the function near $0$.

Comment: OK but how do we formally state that $g(x)$ is differentiable? since we have to differentiate that to get our result.

Comment: g(x) does not have ANY singularities or infinite points near 0.

Comment: This is how we were taught to say a function is differentiable. I will give it for $f$. Since polynomials and cosine functions are differentiable, then the product of differentiable functions is itself differentiable so $f(x)=x\cos(x)$ is differentiable. Hence $f$ is differentiable. How do I state this for $g$?

Comment: Depends how far back you want to go. But if you know that $\sin x$ is differentiable strictly increasing on $(-\pi/6,\pi/6)$, then you should be covered by whatever version of the differentiability of inverse functions has been done in your course.

Comment: What if I said, since $sin(x)$ is differentiable and strictly increasing on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, then the inverse function $\arcsin(x)$ is differentiable?